# redis-cli does not work as a docker command

Tags: docker, redis

I have the following redis container running:

```
   version: '3'
   services:
     redis:
       image: 'bitnami/redis:latest'
       environment:
        - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
```

I am trying to access it via my another application by connecting to the network it is in like this:

```
   version: '3'
   services:
     nginx:
       build: .
       #command: tail -f /dev/null
       ports:
        - "8080:80"
   networks:
     default:
      external:
        name: redis
```

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get full-upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install redis-server -y
EXPOSE 80
CMD redis-cli -h app_redis_1 ping
```

Whenever I use the command redis-cli -h app_redis_1 ping as my CMD in my Dockerfile,
I am unable to connect to my redis server. However if I uncomment tail -f /dev/null and exec inside the running container and run this command myself, I can connect without issues. How can I resolve this?

Comment: can you add the command to yml file ? `command: sh -c "redis-cli -h app_redis_1 ping"` instead of dockerfile ? also where are container log ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by moving the commmand to the yml file